# Multiple onOpen() functions in multiple .gs files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm trying to learn Google Apps Script, and I just did a bit of an experiment with creating two **".gs files"** in the same project, each with an onOpen() function.

After saving, closing, and then opening the document, only one of the onOpen() functions ran (the **Sidebar.gs** file).

Do these need to be included in the same file?  Well, I guess I know that it is a work around.  I guess my question is **WHY?**

```
Project:

Code.gs:
    function onOpen() {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu("PACKT").addItem("Greeting","greeting").addToUi();
    }

    function greeting() {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("Greeting", "Hello World!", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    }

Sidebar.js:

    function onOpen() {
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<button onclick="alert(\'Hello World!\');">Click Me</button>').setTitle("My Sidebar");
    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *never* have two functions with the same name in the same namespace. It simply doesn't make sense: which of them should be executed when `functionName()` call happens? (In reality, the function that was last to be defined will be the surviving one; with the rest lost without trace).

In particular, you should not have two onOpen functions within the same project, be it one file or separate (the files share the namespace, meaning that the functions in one file can be called from the other as if they were in the same file).

But your **one** onOpen() function can simply call whatever functions need to run:

```
function onOpen() {
  doThisThing();
  doAnotherThing();
}
```

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the explanation.  Yeah, I'd put both things into one, and they both worked, I just wanted to know why you can't do both.  It's not something I'd planned to do, just experimenting in case I have a lot of files and functions contained in a project later down the road.  Again, thanks!

Comment: I would also like to point out, that you can have as many `.gs` files as you like, but in terms of how Google Apps Script will work with it will be exactly the same as if they are all on one file. The seperate `.gs` files serve the single purpose of making navigating your code easier. You can also have several functions use the installable `onOpen` trigger, however I believe that you will have no control over which gets executed first.